# Cannot build app in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I recently started using Android studio. I am learning through tutorials, I made a part of flicker app that downloads raw data. When every I try to run it I get this error in "messages" tab:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find any matches for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+ as no versions of com.android.support:appcompat-v7 are available.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
>        Required by:
>            FlickrBrowser:app:unspecified

And console shows this error:

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>     Could not find any matches for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+ as >no versions of com.android.support:appcompat-v7 are available.
>      Searched in the following locations:
>          https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
>          https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
>      Required by:
>          FlickrBrowser:app:unspecified
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 8.603 secs

My MainActivity:

```
package org.example.flickrbrowser;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GetRawData getRawData = new GetRawData("https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=android,lollipop&format=json");
    getRawData.execute();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

GetRawData.class:

```
 package org.example.flickrbrowser;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpConnection;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by Shahbaz on 07/08/15.
 */

enum DownloadStatus {
IDLE, PROCESSING, NOT_INITIALISED, FAILED_OR_EMPTY, OK
};

public class GetRawData {

private String LOG_TAG = GetRawData.class.getSimpleName();
private String mData;
private String mGetRawUrl;
private DownloadStatus mDownloadStatus;

public GetRawData(String mGetRawData) {
    this.mGetRawUrl = mGetRawData;
    this.mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.IDLE;
}


public void reset() {
    this.mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.IDLE;
    this.mGetRawUrl = null;
    this.mData = null;
}


public String getmGetRawUrl() {
    return mGetRawUrl;
}

public DownloadStatus getmDownloadStatus() {
    return mDownloadStatus;
}

public void execute() {
    this.mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.PROCESSING;
    DownloadRawData downloadrawdata = new DownloadRawData();
    downloadrawdata.execute(mGetRawUrl);
}

public class DownloadRawData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public void onPostExecute(String webData) {
        mData = webData;
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "data returned is:" + mData);
        if (mData == null) {
            if (mGetRawUrl == null) {
                mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.NOT_INITIALISED;
            } else {
                mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.FAILED_OR_EMPTY;
            }
        } else {
            mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.OK;
        }


    }

    public void doInBackgroud(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlconnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        if (params == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try {

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlconnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlconnection.connect();

            InputStream inputstream = urlconnection.getInputStream();
            if (inputstream == null) {
                return null;
            }
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
            return buffer.toString();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlconnection != null) {
                urlconnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }


    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the Android support libraries in your SDK? See https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html for instructions.

Comment: Yes I have Android support libraries installed.

Comment: Ops, dont have Android Support Repository, downloading now.

Comment: Getting this error: Error:(57, 12) error: GetRawData.DownloadRawData is not abstract and does not override abstract method doInBackground(String...) in AsyncTask

Comment: that error is because you failed to spell "background" correctly in your method name! In any case, this question appears to be solved and if you need more help, you should post a different SO question.

Comment: omg! Worked now. Its solved yeah, if you like, you can post your comments as answer and I can select it as best answer.

Comment: Try using 22.2.+, being more specific about the minor version (not just 22.+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure you've downloaded the [Android Support Repository](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) in your Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the Android Support Repository from  your android SDK. That is what you are missing. Then it should build fine

Answer (score 0):

From your Android Studio:

> Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager

Wait for the SDK manager to be fully loaded. Then check the option `Android Support Repository` under `Extras` section, next click on <kbd>Install Packages</kbd> to download and install this package.